# how to pass arguments to existing process instance in c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, cmd

I am using ffmpeg and I have start a process and I want to pass an argument to same instance after its start, so how to do this in c sharp any resource. Basically I am using ffmpeg to recored desktop screen and ffmpeg recording can be stop with "q" word.

Comment: Have a look at standard input redirection here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Comment: Maybe `WshShell.SendKeys "q"`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to just send `q` to the process. Probably SendKeys

Comment: yes just want to send q for stop process.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually asking how to send *input* to a process, as if you had typed in its console.

Create the `Process` with the `RedirectStandardInput` property set, then write to its `StandardInput` stream.

Comment: yes how to input a runing process, can you give demo resource, thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx